# For FRR BGP config, do I need add route to null0 for my network like Cisco require?

Tags: cisco, bgp

I used to see Cisco's approach when configure BGP:

```
router bgp 64511
  network 101.10.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0
...
ip route 101.10.0.0 255.255.255.0 null0
```

that is, I need to add the network to routing table so I can advertise it.

Now I need to configure FRR routing suite which mostly mimics the Cisco's config language, and I really doubt if I should (or shouldn't ) add the line `route ... null0`.

The idea behind adding the line is that Cisco used to require that, idea behind not adding is that Linux (which is underline layer) won't be happy to see extra subnet in its routing table.

Please advice!

(Sorry if I misplace the question, not aware where network questions should go to).

Answer (score -1):

Any routing protocol is working this way: it is sharing routes from it's own routing table to the next hop. You don't need to add route to the Null0 (route to nowhere) if you already have it in your routing table (got it from other hop or it is configured for another interface).
Route to the Null at the example used to add it to the local routing table of the device.
BTW using route to the Null0 is good way if you want to summarize you networks and advertise only this one big network instead of lot of small networks. Routing still be working (because small network have highter priority) and if you will get packets to the host to non existing network it will just drop it by rule => Null0.